# Add WhatsApp social share in Sitefinity

Tags: whatsapp, sitefinity

By default, Sitefinity has links for facebook, google, twitter etc but not for WhatsApp. How do I add this as a provider?

Answer (score -1):

IMO, don't use sitefinity OOTB sharing, just plug in AddThis

https://www.addthis.com/blog/tag/whatsapp/

Comment: Yeah, ended up creating my own... Thanks